# Why is only the first value in my dictionary printing

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value-store

Given the code below - 2 dictionaries and for loops.

If I un-indent the line `sim_choice = raw_input("\nPlease enter item code for the SIM card you want?: ")` the print statement above it `print(" " + str(value))` prints all the values in the sims dictionary but then the else statement becomes void. Currently the output is only printing the first value in sims? example:

```
Please tell me your name? X
Hello X
Please enter item code for the phone or tablet you want?: BPCM
Item Code Chosen BPCM['Phone', 'Description: Compact', 'price', 29.99]
As you chose a phone, would you like a SIM free or Pay As You Go for - ['Phone', 'Description: Compact', 'price', 29.99]

Item Code: SMNO
 ['SIM card', 'Description: SIM Free (no SIM card purchased)', 'price', 0.0]

Please enter item code for the SIM card you want?:
```

I cannot see why it wont print all values from sims dictionary in its current state?

```
device = {
    'BPCM' : ['Phone', 'Description: Compact', 'price', 29.99],
    'BPSH' : ['Phone', 'Description: Clam Shell', 'price', 49.99],
    'RTMS' : ['Tablet', 'Description: RoboTab - 10-inch screen and 64GB memory', 'price', 299.99],
    'RTLM' : ['Tablet', 'Description: RoboTab - 10-inch screen and 256 GB memory', 'price', 499.99],
    } 

sims = {    
    "SMNO" : ['SIM card', 'Description: SIM Free (no SIM card purchased)', 'price', 0.00],
    "SMPG" : ['SIM card', 'Description: Pay As You Go (SIM card purchased)', 'price', 9.99],
    }

print("Hello customer, here is your list of phones or tablets. Please choose a phone or tablet by entering your name and the item code:")  
for key, value in device.items(): 
    print("\nItem Code: " + key)
    print(" " + str(value)) 
name = raw_input("\nPlease tell me your name? ") 
print("Hello " + name)
device_choice = raw_input("Please enter item code for the phone or tablet you want?: ") 

if device_choice in device.keys():
    print("Item Code Chosen " + device_choice + str(device[device_choice])) 
sim_cards = ['BPCM', 'BPSH']
if device_choice in sim_cards:
    print("\nAs you chose a phone, would you like a SIM free or Pay As You Go for - " + str(device[device_choice])) 
    for key, value in sims.items():
        print("\nItem Code: " + key)
        print(" " + str(value)) 
        sim_choice = raw_input("\nPlease enter item code for the SIM card you want?: ") 
    else: 
        print("Item Code Chosen " + device_choice + str(device[device_choice]))
```

Comment: Please reduce the example code and example output to the absolute minimum required to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `raw_input` is a blocking statement, meaning it will stop your code there until an event (user input in this case) happens.

To fix the problem with your `else` statement, you should un-indent it to be aligned with its `if` counterpart.

Comment: You might want to add something about the `else` clause that is valid for a `for` loop, but might be confusing for a beginner. See the [tutorial on controlflow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) on the python doc.

Comment: @Lescurel you are right, I did not want to confuse him.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove an indent from the last 3 lines

```
if device_choice in sim_cards:
    print("\nAs you chose a phone, would you like a SIM free or Pay As You Go for - " + str(device[device_choice])) 
    for key, value in sims.items():
        print("\nItem Code: " + key)
        print(" " + str(value)) 
    sim_choice = raw_input("\nPlease enter item code for the SIM card you want?: ") 
else: 
    print("Item Code Chosen " + device_choice + str(device[device_choice]))
```

Comment: Thanks Alistair - this worked! simple indentations causing headache! :)